# Visualize planes in reality kit and place texture in tile format

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit, realitykit

I'm trying to detect plane with table classification and I want to cover the table with an image. Imagine a chessboard covering the entire table surface.
My approach here is to detect planes (which I can) and use the attached image to get to repeat cover the table.

I tried doing it in both reality kit and SceneKit and reality kit gives the best results in terms of occlusion if there are objects on the table or if the table is near a wall or something.

I was able to achieve it in SceneKit by using the contentsTransform with wrapS and wrapT, having a repeated tile format.

But when I do it in RealityKit, the texture just stretches along the entire plane as more and more of the plane is detected. Can someone point me in the right direction here? I am using a lidar enabled device.

my image

[image: chessboard]

in reality kit

[image: reality]

in scenekit

[image: scenekit]

Comment: Have you tried using [MTLSamplerDescriptor's sAddressMode and tAddressMode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlsampleraddressmode/repeat)?

Comment: I did see those. But tbh not sure how to use those to create a new texture.  As far as I know, I need metal know how to do it

Comment: Fyi, I was able to hack a solution but leaving the bounty open for anyone who can answer it.